# Kubuntu python environment pip installation too slow

Tags: apt, kubuntu, python, pip, 23.10

I recently switched to Kubuntu from windows. When I create a python virtual environment and try installing packages using pip, the download and installation process take too long. But the installations are smooth and fast in base environment.

```
OS: Ubuntu 23.10 
Kernel: Linux 6.5.0-26-generic
Python: 3.12.1
pip: 23.3.1
```

I am new to linux and don't know much, I have tried temporarily disabling Ipv6 as mentioned in this [stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50787522/extremely-slow-pip-installs) using following commands, but it still doesn't seem to work.

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

**Edit:**
I am using built in environment created by PyCharm and creating environment in Vscode using following command:

```
python3 -m venv .venv
```

By too slow I mean the download rate, when I install any package suppose pandas then it shows the download speed at something like 900 kbps then it gradually decreases almost to 12 kbps (I haven't stayed any longer to check) also the estimated time for downloading also increases.

And the download rate for kubuntu packages on system are not slow, they occur instantly. Also I tried installing packages in my conda environment and the installations don't take that long when installing with conda but when pip is used, the download rate starts to decrease like before.

**Update:** I tried and looked around different versions, and this particular happened while I was trying to install an old version of numpy(1.23.4) and packages that are download through github such as spacy en_core_web_sm.

Comment: Please edit your question and add details how you installed the Python virtual environment module.
Please also add details on what you experience as "too slow". Is resolving the name of the module to download slow? Is the download rate slow? When you do other network-based operations like updating the Kubuntu packages on the system running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`?